# dict and fixed argument in python string

Tags: python, string

```
msg_string = "my score %d and zone %(zone_name)s"
```

Here,for score my value is: 25, and zone_name is West_Rocker

how can i use above string in my code. I searched a lot to fulfil it, no way found.

I am bound to not change msg_string.

Comment: Do you have actual requirements for this string?

Comment: thanks, I will try to change my original string

Answer (score 2):

You appear to want to mix both positional and named substitutions using `%` interpolation with the same format string. Unfortunately there is no way to do so.

The presence of the `%(zone_name)s` within the format string will generate an exception (`TypeError: format requires a mapping`) if used with a tuple. If used with a dict it will also generate an exception (`TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not dict`).

If there really is no way to change this string, since you know which substrings you wish to replace you could try something like

```
result = msg_string.replace('%d', "25").replace('%zone_name', "West_Rocker")
```

Comment: I know it, but somehow I got this string and print it in my project, Those strings are constant.I am not allowed to change.

Answer (score 0):

I would use one of the following bits:

### Named

```
msg_string = "my score {score:d} and zone {zone_name}".format(score=25, zone_name="West_Rocker")
```

### Positional

```
msg_string = "my score {:d} and zone {}".format(25, "West_Rocker")
```

For more formatting help [check the python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since using `format` method is not work in mixed format.

Lets play tricks on this case, try `re` module.

```
import re

msg_string = "my score %d and zone %(zone_name)s"

score_list = [
    {'value': 25, 'zone_name': "West_Rocker"},
    {'value': 25, 'zone_name': "East_Rocker"},
]
for score in score_list:
    cur_msg_string = msg_string
    cur_msg_string = re.sub(r'\%d', str(score['value']), cur_msg_string)
    if re.search(r'\%\((\w*)\)s', cur_msg_string):
        tar_items = re.search(r'\%\((\w*)\)s', cur_msg_string).groups()
        for item in tar_items:
            cur_msg_string = re.sub(r'\%\((\w*)\)s', score[item], cur_msg_string)
    print(cur_msg_string)
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
my score 25 and zone West_Rocker
my score 25 and zone East_Rocker
```